# Save Workbook As Shared

Tags: excel, vba, blueprism

I am using VB (through Blueprism) to try and save a workbook as a shared workbook. handle, workbookname and filename are all inputs.
Error message:

```
Page: Save Workbook As
Stage: SaveWorkbookAs
Type: Error
Action: Validate
Description: Compiler error at line 8: 'xlShared' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
Repairable: No
```

Code:

```
newworkbookname = ExecWithTimeout(Timeout, "Save Workbook As",
Function()
Dim wb as Object  = GetWorkbook(handle,workbookname)
Dim excel as Object = wb.Application

excel.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.SaveAs(filename)
wb.AccessMode =xlShared
excel.DisplayAlerts = True

Return wb.Name
End Function)
```

Answer (score 2):

Running this from Blueprism almost certainly means you are not within a scope where the Excel constants are available to you, therefore you need to pass the explicit integer value that it stands in for (in this case 2) [according to the XlSaveAsAccessMode enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlsaveasaccessmode)

Comment: Thanks, have I not done this already though? Could you advise what my code should be?

Comment: No, you've referred using the constant (wb.AccessMode = xlShared) - The error is telling you xlShared is not set because it's outside of the scope of Excel where that has any meaning so it thinks it's a local variable - try wb.AccessMode = 2 instead (2 being the explicit value that xlShared stands for)

Comment: Apologies for the delay here. This has gotten an error: Internal : Could not execute code stage because exception thrown by code stage: Public member 'AccessMode' on type 'Workbook' not found.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Blueprism, but that error seems to point to either the AccessMode property itself, or the setting of it to shared as unavailable - I also don't see AccessMode listed as an explicit property or method in the enum docs, so  as you are already doing a SaveAs prior, it might be you have more success setting shared there as part of the save method? AccessMode is a parameter of the SaveAs method, maybe that's where the confusion lies, in that it can't be set directly, but only as part of the save operation.

wb.SaveAs (fileName:=filename, AccessMode:=2)